# How do I check an item in a CheckedListBox when I use DragDrop

Tags: c#

I am using a drag and drop function on a CheckedListBox, for adding external files and changing order of items. Both those things are working (kind of) now. But the problem is that now you can't check a box.

*The moment you check it - it gets unchecked.* I think it has to do with the DragDrop event handler. It doesn't matter if I have CheckOnClick on or off in the properties (I want it off, since you should be able to select an item without checking it).

I want the item to get checked when clicked (after selected) and I want it to stay checked when moved up and down in the box

Here are two handler I use for it:

```
private void missionsBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (missionsBox.SelectedItem == null) return;
            missionsBox.DoDragDrop(missionsBox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void missionsBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = missionsBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    int index = missionsBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
    missionsBox.Items.Remove(data);
    missionsBox.Items.Insert(index, data);

}
```

Very grateful for any help here. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void missionsBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = missionsBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    int index = missionsBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
    missionsBox.Items.Remove(data);
    missionsBox.Items.Insert(index, data);

    //try this?
    missionsBox.Items[index + 1].Selected = True;

}
```

Comment: Thank you but that only gives the error:

'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)